# casting template value parameter

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have a template class that has a boolean template argument.  Is there a legal way to cast it to a reference to the same object but with the boolean inverted?

As an illustrating example, below I have a Matrix class whose transpose can be represented by the same object data, but with the "transposed" template parameter reversed.

```
template <bool transposed>
class Transposable_matrix
{
    ...
    Transposable_matrix<!transposed>& transpose()
    {
        static_cast<Transposable_matrix<!transposed>& >(*this);
    }
};
```

The "transpose()" method above attempts to transpose the object without performing a copy, by simply returning a reference to the itself but with the transposed flag inverted.  However, probably unsurprisingly, the cast operation fails at compile time.  Is there an acceptable way of doing this?  I'm guessing reinterpret_cast provides no guarantees of correctness.   I could use a proxy object to represent the transposed object, but that would involve refactoring the entire class.

**Edit**

After using reinterpret cast, all my unit tests are passing.  But reinterpret cast makes me nervous--does this fall under the category of "undefined behavior" and I just got lucky? Or since the two types (`Matrix<true>` and `Matrix<false>`) have identical members, should I be safe?

**Edit 2**
Would it help to note that this class has no virtual methods?  So it seems like a bit-for-bit copy of the data members should be valid, regardless of the transposed state, so a c-style cast (or reinterpret cast) should always do what I expect, right?

Comment: If you want to change the "type" at runtime, I don't think the template parameter is in any way useful.

Comment: It allows me to do compile-time dimension checking for matrix arithmetic, which is actually quite useful.  I can know the dimension of the result of a matrix multiplication at compile-time, which allows me to allocate the result on the stack instead of the heap--a big win for my application. And I can accomplish it using reinterpret cast in the sample above, I was just wondering if this is undefined behavior.

Comment: It depends on what the class contains, but it would be sort-of better if you could return an instance by value. I can't really imagine what would be the meaning of `Matrix<false> obj; Matrix<true>& ref = a.transpose();` The original `obj` is still there but it is transposed, although the type says otherwise??

Comment: The original obj is unmodified, and ref is a "view" of obj in transposed form and all operations on it will simply reverse their indexing order.  For example, obj(i,j) == ref(j,i) and &obj(i,j) == &ref(j,i) for all i,j.  And  ref(i,j) = 1234; assert(obj(j,i) == 1234).

Comment: Also, it lets you do assignment into the transposed version, Matlab-style:  mat_2x3.transpose() = mat_3x2;   This wouldn't be possible with return-by-value.

Comment: Technically this reinterpret_cast should be undefined behavior, although in practice you are very likely to get away with it. - Wouldn't it be possible to make it just hold a pointer to the matrix they are views of, so that they could be easily manipulated by value?

Comment: Thanks for the answer; post it in an answer and I'll accept it.  Regarding the refactor you suggested, I think storing the pointer would require either dynamic allocation or esoteric ownership semantics, both of which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

> The "transpose()" method below attempts to transpose the object without performing a copy, by simply returning a reference to the itself but with the transposed flag inverted.

That is not possible.

For any value of `transposed` (which is boolean), `Transposable_matrix<true>` and `Transposable_matrix<false>` are two different and incompatible types. One cannot be casted to another using `static_cast`.

Comment: like I said: "However, probably unsurprisingly, the cast operation fails at compile time."  I'm wondering if there's a safe way to do this with an unsafe cast, since I know that the data fields and methods are identical.